# How to save file with its original name in public folder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I m trying to save the files from default to new location (in public/files), and want to save them with their original name, I update my code but that code isn't working:

Code which I update from the previous one:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
    request()->validate([
        'filename' => 'required',
    ]);
    $files = $request->hasfile('filename');
    $files->move(public_path('files'), $new_name);
    foreach($request->file('filename') as $file) {
            File::create([
                'filename' => $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
        ]);
    }

    return redirect('/file')->with('success', 'File Uploaded Successfully');
 }
```

My original/current working code:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
    request()->validate([
        'filename' => 'required',
    ]);
    $files = $request->file('filename');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
            File::create([
                'filename' => $file->getClientOriginalExtension(),
        ]);
    }

    return redirect('/file')->with('success', 'File Uploaded Successfully');
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please review the answer and give feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED**

**Problem 1** : Using keywords already taken by laravel such as **File**,

**Solution** : Rename the model file along with migration example :-

Model File : **UploadedFile.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UploadedFile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'filename',
        'path'
    ];
    protected $table = 'uploadedFiles';
}
```

Migration File : **2019_06_24_072153_create_uploaded_files_table.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUploadedFilesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('uploadedFiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('filename');
            $table->string('path');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('uploadedFiles');
    }
}
```

**Problem 2** : There is no symlink is created in public folder (It is highly recommended to store files in storage folder instead of just public)

**Solution** :  Remove the folder already created as storage and run this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Now in **FileController** this is how you store multiple images into storage folder and in database :-

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{ 
    request()->validate([
    'filename' => 'required',
    ]);
    if($request->hasFile('filename')){
        $files = $request->file('filename');
        foreach($files as $file){
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            Storage::disk('public')->put('files/'.$filename, File::get($file));
            UploadedFile::create([
                'filename' => $filename,
                'path'     => url('storage/files/'.$filename)
            ]);
        }
    }
    return redirect('/file')->with('success', 'File Uploaded Successfully');
}
```

In blade file simple call path because we've already saved path into database

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ $file->path }}">
```

After making all changes run following commands

```
composer update
php artisan config:cache
composer dumpa
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

In case if you're using Ubuntu you need to give permission as well

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx  /opt/lampp/htdocs/multifiles2/
chmod 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/multifiles2/storage/logs/laravel-2019-06-24.log //In case if log file is not accessible
```

Comment: now nthing is happening and files are not uploading

Comment: I made the files folder in public/folder    not in storage/app/public

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'D:\xampp\tmp\phpF3B2.tmp' in 'field list' (SQL: select `D:\xampp\tmp\phpF3B2`.`tmp` from `files`)

Comment: after changing the model name:      include(D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\multifiles2\vendor\composer/../../app/File.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195464/discussion-between-vipertecpro-and-programmer0001).

Comment: Pleas check man i did it https://www.loom.com/share/d3532c608c3d4a038b2fa9c2683d2c68

Comment: I sent you email please review and check and if it working please accept the answer and upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you'll need to do is:

1. Configure Laravel to use the "**public**" folder for storing your files. You can do this by editing **config/filesystems.php** and adding the following code in to the **disks** array:

```php
        'disks' => [
            // This is the block to add
            'my-disk' => [
                'driver' => 'local',
                'root' => public_path(), // Here we tell, that we want to save to the **public** folder
                'url' => env('APP_URL'),
                'visibility' => 'public',
            ],
            // Block end

            'local' => [
                'driver' => 'local',
                'root' => storage_path('app'),
            ],

            'public' => [
                'driver' => 'local',
                'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
                'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
                'visibility' => 'public',
            ],

            's3' => [
                'driver' => 's3',
                'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
                'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
                'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
                'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
                'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            ],

        ],
```

2. Save your file to this new disk:

```php
if ($request->hasFile('filename')) {
    $file = $request->file('filename');
    $path = Storage::disk('my-disk')->putFileAs('files', $file, $file->getClientOriginalName()); // Here the first argument for putFileAs is the subfolder to save to
}
```

Comment: Driver [] is not supported.

Comment: You might have messed the configuration block. I've edited the answer to contain the full **disks** config.